# Button function in a SendGrid Email to Trigger an external Webhook

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

forgive my naivete in asking this question, but I'm hoping someone can help me.

I have an email I send out through the SendGrid api using a dynamic template. The content of the email is different for each user I send it to (highly curated). I send products, their name, info, and a link to buy them.

I am looking to create a "LIKE" button next to each product for the user to interact with in the email and provide feedback on that product. That is, if they like that product but don't want to click to buy yet, they can hit "LIKE" and I'll be informed.

I am thinking I would do this through a webhook using something like integromat where a click of the button would trigger the webhook and then I would use something like airtable to update information.

Is something like this feasible? Would I just put the webhook URL in the href tag of a button? Is it possible to trigger the webhook AND then redirect to a window/tab that would acknowledge that the button was clicked?

Thank you for any feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Links in an email will open a web browser outside of the email. This will make an HTTP request to the URL that you set as the HREF for the link (`<a>`). So, you can point that HREF directly at an endpoint on your own application and handle the request, storing the data about which user liked which product and rendering or redirecting the user to a confirmation page.

I think you may be complicating the idea by introducing the term webhook to this. I also see no reason you would want to include a third-party like Integromat to the proceedings.

Comment: Thank you for your response! My sister works at Twilio!

So I was thinking it was going to be a generic button  that any user would click and it would be attached to dynamic data depending on the user. The same button would then be used for each product. I thought the webhook would then allow me to pass information about the user/product so I know who clicked what.

But thinking about it more, I guess I can just look at who clicked what in the activity screen and I imagine I would be able to tell which button was clicked, even though they are all the same and lead to the same URL.

Comment: You could build the URL with query parameters in it that have both the product and the user identifiers (you can add that with dynamic template data). Ultimately, a webhook is just an HTTP request, and when a user clicks a link to a site, they make an HTTP request to your application, so you can almost treat them the same, except with the user link you need to render something or redirect to a page that does render something.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this Phil. Thanks to your suggestion, I got something to work.

I was hoping I could bug you for one last, hopefully quick, thing.

Is it possible within HTML/within an email to create a faux-onClick event without using JS? I've created the buttons as I mentioned above which sends the user to my own page thank-you page. What would be ideal is if I could do some sort of onClick thing within the email itself so the user is aware of their action.

Given I've never really seen this in an email body, I'm not sure it's possible. And I know you can't use JS in emails..

Comment: I feel like clicking on a link and opening a web browser or a new browser tab should make a user aware that they did something. You could maybe do something like this [click to reveal](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/how-to-make-an-interactive-email-with-click-to-reveal-code/) feature. Alternatively, to keep the interactivity within the email you could explore [AMP for email](https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-interactive-amp-email-twilio-sendgrid), which sort of lets you use JS in emails, but it only supported in some clients.